# Testing two object with operator <, <=, etc

Tags: c#, if-statement, reflection

Long story short, i have, in C#, a function that posses two "object" (yes the class !) representing potentially a primitive type (excluding bool) and i want to test them.
Here is a code to explain it better :

```
public void Compare(object value1, object value2) {
    if(value1 < value2)
        //do something
    if(value1 > value2)
        // do something else...
 }
```

But as you may know it's not possible... Is there a way to do it ?

Comment: Overload the `>` and `<` operators.

Comment: You could attempt a cast to IComparable

Comment: @TravisJ : if i overload them i'll still have to do the test for each of the types.
 GlorinOakenfoot : i have tried : 
    IComparable comp = value as IComparable;
    IComparable comp2 = this._response as IComparable;
    if(comp > comp2) {}

But it gives me the error : operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type IComparable and IComparable

Comment: Ah, right, comparing type of object. I see what you are getting at.

Comment: If the problem is uncertainty about being a primitive or an Object, why would not you use Type t = typeof  and then test IsPrimitive?

Comment: You don't use `>` or `<` directly with `IComparable`. Use `CompareTo()`. [See more here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.compareto(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: To use `IComparable` the objects need to be of the same type.  How do you compare `4.5` and `"cat"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this by casting both objects to `dynamic`. This will cause the **runtime** to determine how to compare the two objects instead of the **compiler**. This way the compare function can be executed with any object (including primitives) that overload the `<` and `>` operators.

```
public void Compare(object value1, object value2) {
    if ((dynamic)value1 < (dynamic)value2)
        // do something
    if ((dynamic)value1 > (dynamic)value2)
        // do something else...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make your method generic and add a constraint to allows only `IComparable<>` types:

```
public void Compare<T>(T value1, T value2) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    if (value1.CompareTo(value2) < 0)
    //do something
    if (value1.CompareTo(value2) > 0)
    // do something else...
}
```

Or you can use `Comparer.Default.Compare()` method, works for numeric types:

```
public static void Compare(object value1, object value2)
{
    if (Comparer.Default.Compare(value1, value2) < 0)
        Console.WriteLine(1);

    if (Comparer.Default.Compare(value1, value2) > 0)
        Console.WriteLine(0);
}
```

But in both cases `value1` and `value2` must be of the same type

Comment: I was wondering if value1 and value2 are always the same type

Comment: @CRice : they are ! Even though there are not, a simple value1.getType == value.getType will fix the deal.

Comment: @ArturoMenchaca : that's a good solution, thanks for the help.